# Woocommerce id was called incorrectly . Product properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

hi i get some error from wp.
log is

Notice: id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-properties-should-not-be-accessed-directly-2/

so i tried with reference to the corresponding url.

change code `$product->get_name();`

It was changed to the above code and operated normally.
But after yesterday's Woocommerce update, the code no longer worked.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Sorry but [`WC_Product` `get_name()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L151-L160) method is correct and exist…  **The method `get_title()` is just an alias of `get_name()` method** …  see here [the source code  of `get_title()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1697-L1704) … The *"ID called incorrectly"* is about using `$product->get_id()` instead of `$product->id`…

Answer (score 2):

i resolved.

```
echo esc_attr($product->get_title());
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Sorry but [`WC_Product` `get_name()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L151-L160) method is correct and exist… So that has nothing to do with accessing product properties as here it's about methods that exist and are allowed… **The method `get_title()` is just an alias of `get_name()` method** …  see here [the source code  of `get_title()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1697-L1704)